# What is the difference between IDREF and IDREFS in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

What is the difference between IDREF and IDREFS in XSD?
I know they both reference the ID attribute, but what is the difference? When each one of them is used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An attribute of type IDREF is a reference to some other element with an attribute of type ID.

An attribute of type IDREFS is a list of references to elements with ID attributes, separate by spaces.

An example:

You're creating a family tree.
Each person has 2 parents, a mother and a father. This would be denoted by IDREFS like so:

```
<person person_id="e10001" parent_id="e10002 e10003">
```

with

```
  <!ATTLIST person
person_id ID #REQUIRED
parent_id IDREFS #IMPLIED>
```